# Even after macro substitution can't resolve the variable

Tags: c++, googletest

I am trying to learn gtest. I have my class `Calculator` that I want to test.

```
#pragma  once

// whattotest.cpp
#include <math.h>

class Calculator{
public:
    double squareRoot(const double a) {
        double b = sqrt(a);
        if(b != b) { // nan check
            return -1.0;
        }else{
            return sqrt(a);
        }
    }

    double add (const double a, const double b){
        return (a + b);
    }

    double multiply(const double a, const double b){
        return (a * b);
    }
};
```

I have the test class code below.

```
#include "gtest_example.hpp"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

using namespace std;


class CalculatorTest : public ::testing::Test {

protected:
    virtual void SetUp() {
        calc = new Calculator();
    }
    virtual void TearDown() {
        delete calc;
    }
    Calculator *calc;
};

TEST(CalculatorTest, ShouldReturnSum) {

    SetUp();
    ASSERT_EQ(72, calc->add(36.0, 36.0));
}

TEST(CalculatorTest, ShouldReturnProduct) {
    SetUp();
    ASSERT_EQ(36, calc.multiply(6.0, 6.0));
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

In both the `ASSERT_EQ` lines I get the following errors.

`Even after macro substitution can't resolve the variable calc.`

What am I doing wrong hee.

Comment: There no variable `calc` visible in scope of the test. Of course you have this error. You do not neet `SetUp` at all. Simply create an object in `TEST` function.

Comment: `(b != b) { // nan check`. there exists [`std::isnan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use fixture, you should use macro `TEST_F` instead of `TEST`.

```
class CalculatorTest : public ::testing::Test {
    Calculator calc;
};

TEST_F(CalculatorTest, ShouldReturnSum)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(72, calc.add(36.0, 36.0));
}

TEST_F(CalculatorTest, ShouldReturnProduct)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(36, calc.multiply(6.0, 6.0));
}
```

Without fixture, you might simply do:

```
TEST(CalculatorTest, ShouldReturnSum)
{
    Calculator calc;
    ASSERT_EQ(72, calc.add(36.0, 36.0));
}

TEST(CalculatorTest, ShouldReturnProduct)
{
    Calculator calc;
    ASSERT_EQ(36, calc.multiply(6.0, 6.0));
}
```